# How to resolve disambiguation in Yago/DBpedia?

Tags: sparql, semantic-web, dbpedia

Assuming I am searching for an entity such as "Wizard of Oz" and know I am specifically interested in the book rather then movie or musical.
Which query/method will return correct results on most cases?

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with a query like:

```
SELECT * WHERE {
  ?s <http://dbpedia.org/property/name> ?name .
  ?s a <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Book> .
  FILTER(regex(STR(?name), "wizard of oz", "i"))
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, I am trying to search for "Book" without a specific ontological relatedness so it will also catch entities in the "Childrens_Books" category for example.

Comment: Sure they could...to see it timing out though, unless it's run against a private instance...

Answer (score 1):

You can also do that with DBpedia Lookup:

http://lookup.dbpedia.org/api/search.asmx/KeywordSearch?QueryClass=book&QueryString=wizard+of+oz

Or with DBpedia Spotlight:

http://spotlight.dbpedia.org/rest/candidates?text=wizard+of+oz+book

Comment: The results for the second link mostly contain the musical, then the film/TV show and nothing about the book...

Comment: The best way of disambiguating text is using Spotlight indeed. But the result gets way better when some context is given (not only the book title).

Answer (score 0):

As every book, and only books, have an ISBN, I guess you can take Steve Harris' query and, instead of asking if it is a book, you can ask if it has an ISBN.

```
SELECT * WHERE {
  ?s <http://dbpedia.org/property/name> ?name .
  ?s <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/isbn> ?isbn .
  FILTER(regex(STR(?name), "wizard of oz", "i"))
}
```